# Is it to solve or to solving here?

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

I am not sure which one works better in this context: **to solve** or **to solving**?

...The scholarship in this master's program is a chance for Dania to learn techniques, unexplored in India, designed to use subterranean water as one main source for human supply. However, it is essential to find  sustainable alternatives to avoid draining it all. This is a Challenge she can work **to solving** by adding the insights this program provides to her training as an industrial engineer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the gerund ("solving") here.

There are other problems with this sentence though. You need an article to introduce "challenge". Then it still isn't a complete sentence; it's a noun phrase with no main verb. Finally, you are using conflicting pronouns: first feminine "her" and then masculine "his". A simple way to fix it, but certainly not the only way, is:

> **This is a** challenge she can contribute to **solving** by adding the insights this program provides to **her** training as an industrial engineer.

Back to "contribute to + *infinitive*" vs. "contribute to + *gerund*," both are actually possible with different meanings.

> - Will you contribute to saving the rain forest?
> - Will you contribute to save the rain forest?

These are both fine. The first sentence uses [contribute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribute) in this sense:

> **3** *intransitive* : to play a significant part in making something happen

The second uses it in this sense:

> **1** *transitive* + *intransitive* : to give or supply (something, such as money or time) as a part or share

So if someone is *contributing to saving the rain forest*, the meaning is that the person is playing a direct role in saving the rain forest. If they are *contributing to save the rain forest*, the meaning is probably rather that they are donating money to an organization who is actually doing something to save the rain forest.

Comment: @TypelA Is it possible the following: "This is a challenge she can work to solving by adding the insights...". Here I am trying to focus the attention on her direct role.

Comment: @pepo she could work **toward** solving that challenge.

Answer (score 0):

> Challenge she can contribute to solve by adding the insights this
> program provides to his training as an industrial engineer.

"**It is a** challenge she can contribute **to solving** by adding the insights..."

"**It is a** challenge she can try **to solve** by adding the insights..."

"**It is a** challenge she can work **to solve** by adding the insights..."

"**It is a** challenge she can work **toward solving** by adding the insights..."

"**These are** challenge**s** she can contribute **to solving** by adding the insights..."

"**These are** challenge**s** she can try **to solve** by adding the insights..."

Comment: Is it possible the following?:"This is a challenge she can work to solving by adding the insights..."

Comment: @pepo -- no, in that sentence, you need to use 'solve', not 'solving'.